# n-puzzle in Clojurescript

Tags: clojure, sliding-tile-puzzle, clojurescript

I'm in the process of creating a n-puzzle solver in Clojurescript. I have the basic model up and running and can move tiles on the screen. I plan to implement A* or such an algorithm to solve a given puzzle. Before I do that, I welcome any general comments for improving the quality of the code right now.

I am just pasting the most important files only here. The entire repo is [here](https://github.com/nakiya/npuzzle-gen)

**puzzle.cljs**

```
    (ns npuzzle.puzzle
      (:require [cljs.test :refer-macros [deftest testing is run-tests]]
                [clojure.zip :as zip]))

    (defn get-tiles [puzzle] (nth puzzle 0))
    (defn get-size [puzzle] (nth puzzle 1))

    (defn set-tiles [puzzle tiles] (assoc puzzle 0 tiles))

    (defn make-puzzle
      ([size]
       [(conj (vec (range 1 (* size size))) :space) size])
      ([tiles size]
       [tiles size]))

    (defn index->row-col [puzzle index]
      (let [size (get-size puzzle)]
        [(quot index size) (mod index size)]))

    (defn row-col->index [puzzle [row col]]
      (let [size (get-size puzzle)]
        (+ (* row size) col)))

    (defn get-tile [puzzle [row col]]
      ((get-tiles puzzle) (+ (* row (get-size puzzle)) col)))

    (defn get-index-of-space [puzzle]
      (.indexOf (get-tiles puzzle) :space))

    (defn get-space-coords [puzzle]
      (index->row-col puzzle (get-index-of-space puzzle)))

    (defn is-space? [puzzle coords]
      (= :space (get-tile puzzle coords)))

    (defn valid-coords? [puzzle [row col]]
      (let [size (get-size puzzle)]
        (and (>= row 0) (>= col 0)
             (< row size) (< col size))))

    (defn get-adjacent-coords [puzzle [row col]]
      (->> '([0 1] [-1 0] [0 -1] [1 0]) ;;'
           (map (fn [[dr dc]]
                  [(+ row dr) (+ col dc)]))
           (filter #(valid-coords? puzzle %))))

    (defn inversions [puzzle]
      (let [size (get-size puzzle)
            tiles (get-tiles puzzle)
            inversions-fn
            (fn [remaining-tiles found-tiles inversions]
              (if-let [i (first remaining-tiles)]
                (recur (rest remaining-tiles)
                       (conj found-tiles i)
                       (+ inversions (- (dec i) (count (filter found-tiles (range i))))))
                inversions))]
        (inversions-fn (remove #{:space} tiles) #{} 0)))

    (defn is-solvable? [puzzle]
      (let [inv-cnt (inversions puzzle)
            size (get-size puzzle)
            [row col] (get-space-coords puzzle)]
        (if (odd? size)
          (even? inv-cnt)
          (if (even? (- size row))
            (odd? inv-cnt)
            (even? inv-cnt)))))

    (defn can-move? [puzzle coords]
      ;;Check if any one of the adjacent tiles is the space.
      (->> (get-adjacent-coords puzzle coords)
           (filter #(is-space? puzzle %))
           (first)))

    (defn swap-tiles [puzzle coord1 coord2]
      (let [index1 (row-col->index puzzle coord1)
            index2 (row-col->index puzzle coord2)
            tile1 (get-tile puzzle coord1)
            tile2 (get-tile puzzle coord2)
            tiles (get-tiles puzzle)]
        (set-tiles puzzle
                   (-> tiles
                       (assoc index1 tile2)
                       (assoc index2 tile1)))))

    (defn move [puzzle coords]
      (if (can-move? puzzle coords)
        (swap-tiles puzzle coords (get-space-coords puzzle))
        puzzle))

    (defn random-move [puzzle]
      (let [space-coords (get-space-coords puzzle)
            movable-tiles (get-adjacent-coords puzzle space-coords)
            random-movable-tile (nth movable-tiles (rand-int (count movable-tiles)))]
        (move puzzle random-movable-tile)))

    (defn shuffle-puzzle
      "Shuffles by moving a random steps"
      ([puzzle]
       (let [num-moves (+ 100 (rand 200))]
         (shuffle-puzzle puzzle num-moves)))
      ([puzzle num-moves]
       (if (> num-moves 0)
         (recur (random-move puzzle) (dec num-moves))
         puzzle)))
```

**puzzle_test.cljs**

```
(ns npuzzle.puzzle-test
  (:require [cljs.test :refer-macros [deftest testing is run-tests]]
            [npuzzle.puzzle :as pzl]))

(deftest puzzle-tests
  (let [p1 (pzl/make-puzzle 3)]
    (testing "make-puzzle"
      (is (= [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 :space] (pzl/get-tiles p1)))
      (is (= 3 (pzl/get-size p1))))
    (testing "get-tile"
      (is (= 1 (pzl/get-tile p1 [0 0])))
      (is (= 2 (pzl/get-tile p1 [0 1])))
      (is (= 5 (pzl/get-tile p1 [1 1]))))
    (testing "get-index-of-space"
      (is (= 8 (pzl/get-index-of-space p1))))
    (testing "get-space-coords"
      (is (= [2 2] (pzl/get-space-coords p1))))
    (testing "is-space?"
      (is (pzl/is-space? p1 [2 2]))
      (is (not (pzl/is-space? p1 [2 1]))))
    (testing "index->row-col"
      (is (= [1 1] (pzl/index->row-col p1 4)))
      (is (= [2 3] (pzl/index->row-col (pzl/make-puzzle 5) 13))))
    (testing "row-col->index"
      (is (= 4 (pzl/row-col->index p1 [1 1])))
      (is (= 13 (pzl/row-col->index (pzl/make-puzzle 5) [2 3]))))
    (testing "valid-coords?"
      (is (pzl/valid-coords? p1 [1 1]))
      (is (not (pzl/valid-coords? p1 [2 3]))))
    (testing "get-adjacent-coords"
      (is (= #{[0 1] [1 0] [1 2] [2 1]} (into #{} (pzl/get-adjacent-coords p1 [1 1]))))
      (is (= #{[0 1] [1 0]} (into #{} (pzl/get-adjacent-coords p1 [0 0])))))
    (testing "can-move?"
      (is (pzl/can-move? p1 [1 2]))
      (is (pzl/can-move? p1 [2 1]))
      (is (not (pzl/can-move? p1 [1 1]))))
    (testing "move"
      (is (= [1 2 3 4 5 :space 7 8 6] (pzl/get-tiles (pzl/move p1 [1 2]))))
      (is (= [1 2 3 4 :space 5 7 8 6] (pzl/get-tiles (pzl/move (pzl/move p1 [1 2]) [1 1]))))
      (is (= [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 :space] (pzl/get-tiles (pzl/move p1 [0 1])))))
    (testing "inversions"
      (is (= 10 (pzl/inversions (pzl/make-puzzle [1 8 2 :space 4 3 7 6 5] 3))))
      (is (= 41 (pzl/inversions (pzl/make-puzzle [13 2 10 3 1 12 8 4 5 :space 9 6 15 14 11 7] 4))))
      (is (= 62 (pzl/inversions (pzl/make-puzzle [6 13 7 10 8 9 11 :space 15 2 12 5 14 3 1 4] 4))))
      (is (= 56 (pzl/inversions (pzl/make-puzzle [3 9 1 15 14 11 4 6 13 :space 10 12 2 7 8 5] 4)))))
    (testing "is-solvable?"
      (is (pzl/is-solvable? (pzl/make-puzzle [1 8 2 :space 4 3 7 6 5] 3)))
      (is (pzl/is-solvable? (pzl/make-puzzle [13 2 10 3 1 12 8 4 5 :space 9 6 15 14 11 7] 4)))
      (is (pzl/is-solvable? (pzl/make-puzzle [6 13 7 10 8 9 11 :space 15 2 12 5 14 3 1 4] 4)))
      (is (not (pzl/is-solvable? (pzl/make-puzzle [3 9 1 15 14 11 4 6 13 :space 10 12 2 7 8 5] 4)))))
    (testing "shuffle-puzzle"
      (is (pzl/is-solvable? (pzl/shuffle-puzzle (pzl/make-puzzle 4))))
      (is (pzl/is-solvable? (pzl/shuffle-puzzle (pzl/make-puzzle 6))))
      (is (pzl/is-solvable? (pzl/shuffle-puzzle (pzl/make-puzzle 9))))
      (is (not= (pzl/shuffle-puzzle (pzl/make-puzzle 3)) (pzl/make-puzzle 3)))
      (is (not= (pzl/shuffle-puzzle (pzl/make-puzzle 8)) (pzl/make-puzzle 8))))))

(run-tests)
```

**views.cljs**

```
(ns npuzzle.views
  (:require
   [re-frame.core :as re-frame]
   [npuzzle.subs :as subs]
   [npuzzle.events :as ev]))

(defn- on-puzzle-size-changed [e]
  (re-frame/dispatch [::ev/change-puzzle-size (int (-> e .-target .-value))]))

(defn- on-tile-mouse-down [e]
  (let [idx (.getAttribute (-> e .-target) "data-tileindex")]
    (re-frame/dispatch [::ev/move-tile (int idx)])))

(defn- tile-div [idx tile]
  [:div {:style {:text-align :center
                 :padding "15px"
                 :font-size "20px"
                 :border (if (not= :space tile) "1px solid black" :none)
                 :background (if (not= :space tile) :lightblue nil)
                 :height "25px"
                 :width "25px"
                 ;;cursor = default for disabling caret on hover over text
                 :cursor :default}
         :onMouseDown on-tile-mouse-down
         :data-tileindex idx}
   (if (= :space tile)
     " "
     tile)])

(defn- tiles-container [puzzle size tile-fn]
  (into [:div {:style {:display :inline-grid
                       :grid-template-columns (apply str (repeat size "auto "))
                       :grid-gap "2px"
                       :border "2px solid black"}}]
        (map-indexed
         (fn [idx tile]
           (tile-fn idx tile)) puzzle)))

(defn main-panel []
  (let [name (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/name])
        sizes (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/size-choices])
        current-size (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/puzzle-size])
        puzzle (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/puzzle])]
    [:div
     [:h1 "Hello to " @name]
     [:div
      {:style {:padding "10px"}}
      (into [:select {:name "puzzle-size"
                      :on-change on-puzzle-size-changed
                      :defaultValue @current-size}]
            (for [size @sizes]
              (into [:option {:value size} size])))]
     (tiles-container @puzzle @current-size tile-div)]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see anything major. I also don't know Cljs (only Clj), so I apologize if a suggestion of mine doesn't apply to Cljs.

Just a few small things:

Personally, I don't like having function definitions all on one line. Increasingly, I'm even splitting `def` definitions over two lines. I find it generally helps readability. I'd change your definitions at the top to:

```
(defn get-tiles [puzzle]
  (nth puzzle 0))

(defn get-size [puzzle]
  (nth puzzle 1))

(defn set-tiles [puzzle tiles]
  (assoc puzzle 0 tiles))
```

---

And I don't see any sample data, but judging by the first two functions, you seem to be storing the puzzle as a vector "tuple" of `[tiles size]`. You may find that it's neater to store that as a map instead. Something like `{:tiles [...], :size ...}`. That gives you getters for free (as keywords), and makes the structure itself more self explanatory.

---

You're using `:space` as a sentinel value. You may find using a namespaced-qualified version (`::space` internally) is beneficial. I like using `::` keywords when possible because IntelliJ gives better autocomplete suggestions when using namespaced keywords, so it's harder to cause typos.

---

`valid-coords?` can be simplified a bit by taking advantage of "comparison chaining":

```
(defn valid-coords? [puzzle [row col]]
  (let [size (get-size puzzle)]
    (and (< -1 row size)
         (< -1 col size))))
```

You could also use `<=` and `dec` `size` before comparing:

```
(defn valid-coords? [puzzle [row col]]
  (let [size (dec (get-size puzzle))]
    (and (<= 0 row size)
         (<= 0 col size))))
```

---

`is-solvable?` can have some of its nesting reduced using `cond`:

```
(defn is-solvable? [puzzle]
  (let [inv-cnt (inversions puzzle)
        size (get-size puzzle)
        [row col] (get-space-coords puzzle)]
    (cond
      (odd? size) (even? inv-cnt)
      (even? (- size row)) (odd? inv-cnt)
      :else (even? inv-cnt))))
```

I go back and forth between putting the conditions and bodies on the same and separate lines. In this case though, everything is short enough that readability is fine. If I spaced this out like I normally would:

```
(defn is-solvable? [puzzle]
  (let [inv-cnt (inversions puzzle)
        size (get-size puzzle)
        [row col] (get-space-coords puzzle)]
    (cond
      (odd? size)
      (even? inv-cnt)

      (even? (- size row))
      (odd? inv-cnt)

      :else
      (even? inv-cnt))))
```

It becomes huge, although I do think the readability is better in the second version.

---

`(if (> num-moves 0)` can alternatively be written as `(if (pos? num-moves)`.

---

A lot of your tests have a series of `is` checks that are all basically checking the same thing, just with different data:

```
(testing "get-tile"
  (is (= 1 (pzl/get-tile p1 [0 0])))
  (is (= 2 (pzl/get-tile p1 [0 1])))
  (is (= 5 (pzl/get-tile p1 [1 1]))))
```

This can be simplified using [`are`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/are):

```
(testing "get-tile"
  (are [result coord] (= result (pzl/get-tile p1 coord))
    1 [0 0]
    2 [0 1]
    5 [1 1]))
```

That gets rid of a *lot* of explicit duplicate calls and noise.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I will incorporate these in...